# Why doesn't my Perl play nice with Unicode?

Tags: perl, unicode

On my new Arch installation, `perl` doesn't seem to play nice with Unicode. For example, given this input file:

```
ελα ρε
王小红
```

This command should give me the last two characters of each line:

```
$ perl -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file
Îµ
º¢
```

However, as you can see above, I get gibberish. The correct output is:

```
ρε
小红
```

I know that my terminal (`gnome-terminator`) supports UTF-8 since these both work as expected:

```
$ cat file
ελα ρε
王小红
$ perl -pe '' file
ελα ρε
王小红
```

Unfortunately, without `-CIO`, `perl` doesn't deal with the files correctly either:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file
ε
��
```

It also shouldn't be a locale issue:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm guessing I need to install some Perl packages, but I don't know which ones. Some relevant information:

```
$ perl --version | grep subversion
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

$ pacman -Qs unicode
local/fribidi 0.19.7-1
    A Free Implementation of the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm
local/icu 55.1-1
    International Components for Unicode library
local/libunistring 0.9.6-1
    Library for manipulating Unicode strings and C strings
local/perl 5.22.0-1 (base)
    A highly capable, feature-rich programming language
local/perl-unicode-stringprep 1.105-1
    Preparation of Internationalized Strings (RFC 3454)
local/perl-unicode-utf8simple 1.06-5
    Conversions to/from UTF8 from/to characterse
local/ttf-arphic-uming 0.2.20080216.1-5
    CJK Unicode font Ming style
```

How can I get my perl installation to play nice with Unicode?

Comment: To handle unicode I am using [utf8::all](http://search.cpan.org/~doherty/utf8-all-0.016/lib/utf8/all.pm) so your both should work: `perl -Mutf8::all -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file` or `perl -Mutf8::all -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file`.

Comment: @taliezin thanks, that helped. After installing the `utf8::all` module, the command you gave did indeed work as expected. I would still like to have the standard `-CIO` options working though. I shouldn't need to call another module for this.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html -- this is one area where Perl is behind other languages.

Comment: @glennjackman perhaps, but I know this sort of think used to work on my Debian and Choroba [has confirmed](http://superuser.com/a/996388/151431) that it works on his system. So, there should be a way to get it to work on my Arch as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you are describing is standard behaviour on the systems I tested on. `I` and `O` affect stdin and stdout, so this should work:

```
→ cat data | perl -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/'
ρε
小红
```

Whereas this might not:

```
→ perl -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' data
Îµ
º¢
```

There are [two more options to `perl -C`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5B_number%2Flist_%5D*) that produce your desired behaviour.

```
i     8   UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for input streams
o    16   UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for output streams
```

Which is basically saying to perl, use a file open form:

```
open(F, "<:utf8", "data");
```

or you can use `perl -CSD` which is shorthand for `perl -CIOEio`

```
S     7   I + O + E
D    24   i + o
```

Then you get

```
→ perl -CSD -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' data
ρε
小红
```

If the `PERLIO` environment variable is set and includes `:utf8` this behaviour would also be enabled.

It looks like the default behaviour for `perl` isn't modifiable at configure/compile time either (cuonglm comment below). Arch certainly doesn't [set anything.](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/perl) I doubt debian perl packages would modify default behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean when saying `default is easily modifiable at configure/compile time`? AFAICT, the compile time only instruct `perl` to use perl own io abstraction instead of system stdio, it does mean you can set UTF-8 as default encoding layer for `perl`.

Comment: Well, I said I'm not sure if the default was modifiable or not.  I was trying to think of reasons his arch system would be different to a debian system.  Did you mean to write "it doesn't mean" in your last sentence?

Comment: Yes, I mean "it does not mean", my bad typo.

Comment: Thnx. It's been a while since I've needed to compile perl =)

Answer (score 2):

That's not a system issue but the `perl` itself.

`-CIO` only set UTF-8 encoding on `STDIN` and `STDOUT`, two of three `perl` predefined filehandle (you have `-E` for `STDERR` as well).

When you use:

```
perl -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file
```

`perl` use diamond operator `<>` for processing file. Since when diamond operator `<>` used [open (with two arguments form)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27198594/2218718) to create new filehandle for each file from command line, these filehandle won't be affected by the UTF-8 encoding you set on `STDIN` and `STDOUT`.

So, you can pass the content of file to `perl` through its stdin, and it will work:

```
perl -CIO -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' <file
```

For other options see [@Matt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241134/38906).

---

In case you want `perl` use your locale for default encoding layer, you can use:

```
perl -Mopen=:locale -pe 's/.*(..)$/$1/' file
```

---

When you use `PERLIO` for setting the encoding layer, you should [use `:encoding(uf8)` instead of `:utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html#What-is-the-difference-between-%3Aencoding-and-%3Autf8%3F).

Using `:utf8` skip the encoding step, and can cause problem when reading invalid UTF-8 bytes sequences and leading to security problems.